# Wix MSI is not showing screen to select the "Destination Folder" during installation

Tags: wix

I have below code in my `.wxs` file

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">

  <!-- Start Menu -->
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="InstallProgramMenuFolder" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)" />
  </Directory>

  <?if $(var.Platform)=x64 ?>
    <!-- Program Files (64bit) folder -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)" />
    </Directory>
  <?else?>
    <!-- Program Files (32bit) folder -->
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(loc.ProductNameFolder)" />
    </Directory>
  <?endif?>

</Directory>
```

MSI is successfully getting created, but it's not showing the `Destination Folder` selection screen. After license agreement it starts installation and files are getting copied to default `C:\Program Files (x86)`

I tried to add this

```
         <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
         <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

But this shows tons of build errors

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Duplicate symbol 'CheckBox:LicenseAccepted' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.    MySample.Installer  C:\agent_work\8\s\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\WelcomeEulaDlg.wxs    12

Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Change Dialog Set***: I would look for other **UIRef elements** and change the dialog set to **`<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`** in the one that is "active". There should be only one UIRef element - as in "Highlander style". Your destination folder dialog should now be available once you recompile successfully.

***Dialog Sets***: [WixUI_Mondo](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_mondo.html) is one of the [built-in dialog sets](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html) supplied with WiX, and as you understand it supports a custom installation folder dialog (unlike some of the other dialog sets). I find it to be the better dialog set in practical use, but opinions differ obviously. Give it a test run?

---

***Some Links***:

- [WixUI Dialogs](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_dialogs.html) (the WixUI dialog reference).

Comment: There is no other UIRef in entire project. so I am surprised.

Comment: How do you build the project? Via a batch file or inside Visual Studio? Any wixlibs? Any fragments? Any include files?

Comment: How about UI elements? As opposed to UIRef.

Comment: Found it, I had  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />

Comment: It all compiles now?

Comment: Updated question and accepted the answer! Great help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179925/discussion-between-codetoshare-and-stein-asmul).